# How to use hql to read from hive sorted table by keep the records of a same key into same mapper

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, transform

I am trying to read data from a sorted hive table. The table record a list of user actions, a user will have may actions. for example:

```
column: user_id  time               action
value:  u1      20150607/12:20:25  click_url1
value:  u1      20150607/12:21:25  search "stackoverflow" 
value:  u2      20150607/11:19:00  read news
```

and when insert data to the hive table, the hive sql has used "distribute by user_id sort by user_id, time".

And now I want read data from this table and I think it can reused the sort. But there is one block issue that I need the same user_id record in the same mapper, and the I will write a transform to process the list of action of the same user. But seems when read from the table, I cannot keep the actions of same user id in one mapper. I have tried some ways like :

1) only "set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat;" but seems not work, the user_id is still be partition into two mappers.(but I don't know why, I think only set HiveInputFormat will not do any split)

2) SET mapred.min.split.size=2048000000; to set the min split size into more larger and hope the same part will be into one mapper. But seems the mapper number is some strange(when insert the data into the hive table, there are 2000 reducers, but when I use 2G as the min split size, the mapper number is 1478 ). So I think there also will split the same user id into different mapper.

3)seems can rewrite InputFormat, but I still didn't know how to write it from the examples I found.

Comment: As you already tried something to rewrite you may post the code here

Comment: I didn't write code now, I think there may have some setting can be used directly? As I think one solution is to make one part of the hive table not be split.   Another solution is to write a InputFormat?..But I don't know how to write to till now.